# Azure VM resource usage spikes

Tags: azure, freebsd, azure-virtual-machine

Him im running FreeBSD 10.1 STABLE version on my azure's virtual machine, for about 7 days I can notice cpu and disk usage spikes, also my networking goes down - noone can connect to virtual machine.

Output of 'top' command:

```
CPU:  0.0% user,  0.0% nice,  0.0% system,  0.0% interrupt,  100% idle
    Mem: 18M Active, 395M Inact, 124M Wired, 27M Cache, 88M Buf, 420M Free
    Swap: 1024M Total, 7396K Used, 1017M Free
```

Azure's vm monitor every 6 hours generates spikes, about cpu and disk usage, also CPU usage is higher than my 'top' output says.

[image: Screenshot]

Content of waagent.log

```
2015/12/13 11:56:05 ERROR:HTTP Req: HEAD https://almeria.blob.core.windows.net/almeria/Almeria.almeria.almeria.status?sr=b&sp=rw&se=9999-01-01&sk=key1&sv=2014-02-14&sig=H5JjMf5f%2BxITjTJGtJmtm2TqAFpKwkFalIdQjfg%2F5L0%3D
2015/12/13 11:56:05 ERROR:HTTP Req: Data=None
2015/12/13 11:56:05 ERROR:HTTP Req: Header={'x-ms-version': '2014-02-14', 'x-ms-date': '2015-12-13T10:55:54Z'}
2015/12/13 11:56:05 ERROR:HTTP Err: response is empty.
2015/12/13 11:56:15 ERROR:Socket IOError [Errno 8] hostname nor servname provided, or not known, args:(8, 'hostname nor servname provided, or not known')
2015/12/13 11:56:15 ERROR:Retry=2
2015/12/13 11:56:15 ERROR:HTTP Req: HEAD https://almeria.blob.core.windows.net/almeria/Almeria.almeria.almeria.status?sr=b&sp=rw&se=9999-01-01&sk=key1&sv=2014-02-14&sig=H5JjMf5f%2BxITjTJGtJmtm2TqAFpKwkFalIdQjfg%2F5L0%3D
2015/12/13 11:56:15 ERROR:HTTP Req: Data=None
2015/12/13 11:56:15 ERROR:HTTP Req: Header={'x-ms-version': '2014-02-14', 'x-ms-date': '2015-12-13T10:55:54Z'}
2015/12/13 11:56:15 ERROR:HTTP Err: response is empty.
2015/12/13 11:56:25 ERROR:Socket IOError [Errno 8] hostname nor servname provided, or not known, args:(8, 'hostname nor servname provided, or not known')
2015/12/13 11:56:25 ERROR:Can't get status blob type.
2015/12/13 11:56:25 ERROR:Unknown blob type: None
2015/12/13 11:56:47 ERROR:Socket IOError [Errno 65] No route to host, args:(65, 'No route to host')
2015/12/13 11:56:47 ERROR:Retry=0
2015/12/13 11:56:47 ERROR:HTTP Req: GET /machine/?comp=goalstate
2015/12/13 11:56:47 ERROR:HTTP Req: Data=None
2015/12/13 11:56:47 ERROR:HTTP Req: Header={'x-ms-version': '2012-11-30', 'x-ms-agent-name': 'WALinuxAgent'}
2015/12/13 11:56:47 ERROR:HTTP Err: response is empty.
2015/12/13 11:56:57 ERROR:Socket IOError [Errno 65] No route to host, args:(65, 'No route to host')
2015/12/13 11:56:57 ERROR:Retry=1
2015/12/13 11:56:57 ERROR:HTTP Req: GET /machine/?comp=goalstate
2015/12/13 11:56:57 ERROR:HTTP Req: Data=None
2015/12/13 11:56:57 ERROR:HTTP Req: Header={'x-ms-version': '2012-11-30', 'x-ms-agent-name': 'WALinuxAgent'}
2015/12/13 11:56:57 ERROR:HTTP Err: response is empty.
2015/12/13 11:57:07 ERROR:Socket IOError [Errno 65] No route to host, args:(65, 'No route to host')
2015/12/13 11:57:07 ERROR:Retry=2
2015/12/13 11:57:07 ERROR:HTTP Req: GET /machine/?comp=goalstate
2015/12/13 11:57:07 ERROR:HTTP Req: Data=None
2015/12/13 11:57:07 ERROR:HTTP Req: Header={'x-ms-version': '2012-11-30', 'x-ms-agent-name': 'WALinuxAgent'}
2015/12/13 11:57:07 ERROR:HTTP Err: response is empty.
2015/12/13 11:57:17 ERROR:Socket IOError [Errno 65] No route to host, args:(65, 'No route to host')
```

Comment: Hi Casawir - welcome to StackOverflow. Honestly, I can't tell what you're asking. This isn't a programming question as far as I can tell. Maybe post this to SuperUser or ServerFault? But even so: I'm struggling to understand the question. Not sure how anyone would be able to explain your traffic spikes based on the info you've given.

Comment: I /think/ he's asking if Azure's VM Agent running on the VM, is causing these spikes

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the waagent.log, it looks like the WAAgent running on your FreeBSD VM had issues connecting to the blob store containing the "things" (which I don't know) for WAAgent to work. 
As the HTTP request sent by WAAgent to the URL already contains "sig", I tried simulating its requests using Fiddler tool's "Composer" feature and I got "ok" from my machine :

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Content-Length: 277
>   Content-Type: application/octet-stream
>   Content-MD5: 88aaZTRw2UXc2v/oxHyf/Q==
>   Last-Modified: Mon, 14 Dec 2015 21:24:56 GMT
>   Accept-Ranges: bytes
>   ETag: "0x8D304CD03AEF013"
>   Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
>   x-ms-request-id: 1f7d6bdf-0001-00e1-12b5-3693c5000000
>   x-ms-version: 2014-02-14
>   x-ms-lease-status: unlocked
>   x-ms-lease-state: available
>   x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
>   Date: Mon, 14 Dec 2015 21:25:15 GMT

If you have CURL or WGET installed on your FreeBSD machine, could you please try calling the URL below from your FreeBSD console ? :

https://almeria.blob.core.windows.net/almeria/Almeria.almeria.almeria.status?sr=b&sp=rw&se=9999-01-01&sk=key1&sv=2014-02-14&sig=H5JjMf5f%2BxITjTJGtJmtm2TqAFpKwkFalIdQjfg%2F5L0%3D

If you get anything like below you can conclude that your machine can access to the blob storage :

> "{"version":"1.0","timestampUTC":"2015-12-14T21:30:30Z","aggregateStatus":{"guestAgentStatus":{"version":"WALinuxAgent-2.0.16","status":"Ready","formattedMessage":{"lang":"en-US","message":"GuestAgent is running and accepting new configurations."}},"handlerAggregateStatus":[]}}"

Even though you can reach to the URL with no issues, but you are consistently getting the "ERROR:Socket IOError [Errno 65] No route to host, args:(65, 'No route to host')" error message asking help from Microsoft Support team with "technical" support ticket would be the best way to find out what is going on under the cover in WAAGent

Comment: Please mark my answer "as answer" if it is answered your question